# I can't extract data from suds in python

Tags: python, suds

I have this source in python 2.7

```
from suds.client import Client
#url_service = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL'
url_service= 'http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl'
print ("questo e " , url_service)

client = Client(url_service)
list_of_methods = [method for method in client.wsdl.services[0].ports[0].methods]

print list_of_methods
```

I cannot extract data from this URL, and I have tried with other URLs but with the same results.

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure `client.wsdl.services[0].ports[0].methods` is not `None`?

Comment: makes the same with all the url:

Comment: I can't extract nothing , i need something that sure it works , thanks  a lot if someone can help

Comment: What is the output of `client ` ? What kind of data you aspire to extract?

Comment: I would like to have a list of all the methods , the most complete as possible .